# How to use JDBC written on Windows and deployed to Ubuntu?

Tags: java, mysql, ubuntu, intellij-idea, jdbc

Is it possible to develop a java application using jdbc on a windows laptop, and then deploy the jar to an ubuntu VM?

I have a small application that connects to a database on the VM (using IP address).  This works fine on Windows in IntelliJ if I run it within the IDE.   It also works fine if I move the project to Intellij on Ubuntu and run from within the IDE.  But I want to deploy a JAR file to the Ubuntu platform.   When I do this I get "No suitable driver found for jdbc..."

I have tried:

- Installing jdbc on ubuntu using "sudo apt-get install libmysql-java".
- Adding the Platform Independent current jdbc driver as a library.
- Including this library in the jar artifact when building.
- Adding the ubuntu jdbc to the CLASSPATH (export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/share/java/mysql.jar)

I can't be the only person who wants to develop on Windows and deploy to Ubuntu?

Comment: You just need to add the driver to the runtime classpath, i.e. with the `-cp` switch. No library in the jar, no putting things in `CLASSPATH`. Nothing Ubuntu specific either, it's the same on Windows (or Mac) if you're running from the command line.

Comment: It must work with exactly the same behavior, probably your deployed jar is missing some jar dependency, use java -cp or take a look at Gradle or maven for that

Comment: In a normal Java application, the dependencies are deployed together with the application and either referenced using `-cp` from the startup script, or using the `Class-Path` entry in the manifest of the jar file. You don't normally use operating system installed libraries or things on the system CLASSPATH.

Comment: There are lots of different ways to package a JAR. (Most Java developers are working with frameworks that take care of this for us, be it Jakarta, Spring, Quarkus, whatever.) When I do need to make a little command line Java program, I often end up Googling how to do it. Most recently I used this: https://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven#thymeleaf-1. Just make sure your jdbc driver is listed as a dependency in your pom file. Here's my pom file, for example https://github.com/bcgov/moh-iam/blob/master/ldap-keycloak-etl/pom.xml